# Does the Gmail API skip verification code emails? Python Gmail API

Tags: python, gmail-api

I'm trying to use the Gmail api to attain verification codes for 2FA. However, the following code seems to like literally skip my verification code emails:

```
    def getEmails(self):

        SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']

        creds = None
    
        if os.path.exists(self.CREDENTIALS_PATH+'\\token.pickle'):
    
            with open(self.CREDENTIALS_PATH+'\\token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
                creds = pickle.load(token)

        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(self.CREDENTIALS_PATH+'\\credentials.json', SCOPES)
                creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    
            with open(self.CREDENTIALS_PATH+'\\token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
                pickle.dump(creds, token)
    
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    
        result = service.users().messages().list(userId='me').execute()
    
        result = service.users().messages().list(maxResults=5, userId='me').execute()
        messages = result.get('messages')
    
        for msg in messages:
            txt = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=msg['id']).execute()

            try:
                payload = txt['payload']
                headers = payload['headers']
    
                for d in headers:
                    if d['name'] == 'Subject':
                        subject = d['value']
                    if d['name'] == 'From':
                        sender = d['value']
   
                parts = payload.get('parts')[0]
                data = parts['body']['data']
                data = data.replace("-","+").replace("_","/")
                decoded_data = base64.b64decode(data)
    
                soup = BeautifulSoup(decoded_data , "lxml")
                body = soup.body()

                print("Subject: ", subject)
                print("From: ", sender)
                print("Message: ", body)
                print('\n')
            except:
                pass
```

Is this actually the case? Does the Gmail API skip verification code emails? If not what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: If this is a question about the mechanisms of Gmail, it's going to be off-topic. And BTW if you need to automatically collect 2FA codes, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @KlausD. Sorry I might've not explained my problem well. I'm trying to access an email that was sent from a third party that contains a verification code for that third party website. But when I get the latest 5 emails from my inbox, it literally just skips that email. I've tried a few different ways and it just continues to completely skip it and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

2fa is only needed for sign-in.

What you are doing is Oauth2 requesting authorization of the user to access their gmail account.  In this instance the user running the code is probably already signed in on the machine to their account so 2fa is not needed. Logout of your google account and it should first prompt you to sign-in and ask for 2fa, then you will see the consent screen for Oauth2 after that.  Sign-in (openid connect) and Oauth2 are two different systems.

- Authencation - Signin / OpenId connect
- Authorization - Oauth2 application access to an api.